# Filesystem sandbox for java web application

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jboss6.x

I am developing a web application (deployed on Jboss6) which reads files from base/ro1 and base/ro2, but also creates new files into base/rw. Files can also be deleted from base/rw.

Is there a way to apply a global security policy for this application which can define these restrictions, on the lines of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc3.html?
The application also exposes API to access/manipulate files in these directories. For eg. if I provide an API with a url api/delete?name=file1, I want the delete api to only be able to delete a file under base/rw/. And a url similar to api/delete?name='../ro/*' should be restricted.

Comment: Does your app already run with security manager enabled?

Comment: No, I don't see -Djava.security.manager as an arg while starting up Jboss. There are 5 other apps running inside the same jboss, so I need this restriction applied only on my application.

Comment: Did you consider doing security checks in the application itself in the service layer? Unless you can't trust the code that you run as a part of the app, this would be much more easier and flexible solution, and only slightly less secure.

Comment: The purpose of running a sandbox/security manager is so that the person running Java can protect their system from code they didn't write or don't trust. If you're writing all of the functions that will operate on these files, that's just business rules/logic that you'd code into your application.

Comment: @pingw33n and user1676075, the application could run into tons of classes and evolve to have more APIs. I was hoping to see a central place where I could control this for my application. I get your point about the security manager being used to protect from untrusted code, but not sure why this concept cannot be extended to use for trusted code within app.